# FastCGI WSGI library in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastcgi, wsgi

Does there exist any library that can serve a WSGI application as a FastCGI server, for Python 3? (So that nginx could then proxy requests to it?)

[The Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/webservers.html#setting-up-fastcgi) mention [flup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flup/1.0), but flup doesn't even install in Python 3:

```
% env3/bin/pip install flup
Downloading/unpacking flup
  Downloading flup-1.0.2.tar.gz (49kB): 49kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/me/tmp/env3/build/flup/setup.py) egg_info for package flup
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 17, in 
      File "/Users/me/tmp/env3/build/flup/setup.py", line 2, in 
        from ez_setup import use_setuptools
      File "./ez_setup.py", line 98
        except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 17, in 

  File "/Users/me/tmp/env3/build/flup/setup.py", line 2, in 

    from ez_setup import use_setuptools

  File "./ez_setup.py", line 98

    except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:

                                        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in [snip]
Storing debug log for failure in [snip]
```

Comment: A very quick Google search shows this in the first half dozen results. https://github.com/Pyha/flup-py3.3

Comment: Found another one. It seems the original author Allan Saddi contributes significantly to it: http://hg.saddi.com/flup-py3.0/

Comment: @Nayuki Yes indeed, `flup-py3` has an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/Pyha/flup-py3.3/issues/2) which has been standing open for a couple of years now. In [`flipflop`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flipflop), the great work of Allan Saddi was further simplified.

Answer (score 9):

There is now module called `flup6`. Install it using `pip`

```
./pip install flup6
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected bytes, bytearray, or an object with the buffer interface, str found

it not works with django 1.8 python 3.4

Comment: It looks like `flup6` is the only working `flup` replacement for Python 3. Tried `flup-py3` and `flipflop` on Python 3.5.

Comment: @quasiyoke flipflop will not work in windows, as 'fcntl' can not work in windows.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [flipflop](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flipflop). It's a simplified fork of flup (contains only the FastCGI part) and works fine with Python 3.

Comment: Came across this on Google; this was exactly what I was looking for. Documentation is sparse, but the example on wikipedia is enough:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface#Example_application

Comment: For django, the fcgi on hostmonster.com asks for flup and pip could not able to install it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flup-py3` to solve this problem, as :

`pip3 install flup-py3`

You may need super user privilge to execute this command.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of two options

- [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) - instructions [for CherryPy](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-a-cherrypy-web-server-behind-nginx) from Digital Ocean
- [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) - instructions [for uWSGI](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-uwsgi-web-server-with-nginx) from Digital Ocean

Both support Python 3 and both can create WSGI workers based on other web app code and can be served to NGINX.

As Graham Dumpleton mentioned, CherryPy talks to NGINX via HTTP protocol, while uWSGI talks the 'uwsgi' protocol to nginx instead of the HTTP protocol, although it does also support using HTTP as well. On the application side, both support hosting Python web applications via the WSGI API.

Comment: CherryPy relies on HTTP proxying. uWSGI would be a better choice of the two for nginx as recent nginx versions have support for uWSGI's custom protocol built in.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Good point, reviewed some descriptions, learned from your comment and updated my answer. I hope I understood your comment and linked descriptions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## Use `flipflop` instead

```
pip3 install --upgrade flipflop
```

[`flipflop`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flipflop) is what did the trick for me.
`flup-py3` has an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/Pyha/flup-py3.3/issues/2) which has been standing open for a couple of years now.

Do not forget to [edit the import line](https://github.com/Kozea/flipflop) in your `.fcgi` script to reflect this change towards [using `flipflop`](https://github.com/Kozea/flipflop).