# Version conflict while installing flup

Tags: django, pip, bluehost, flup

I'm trying to get a django site up on bluehost. I already have one running using python2.7, but for this new project I am using python3.5. I've pretty much tried to set everything up the same way that I did before, except using python3. When trying to install flup:

```
pip3 install flup
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Collecting flup
  Using cached flup-1.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/var/tmp/pip-build-mzc6swh8/flup/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ez_setup import use_setuptools
      File "/var/tmp/pip-build-mzc6swh8/flup/ez_setup.py", line 98
        except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /var/tmp/pip-build-mzc6swh8/flup
```

I am guessing that this instance is flup is seeing my python2 version of flup or something and throwing an error. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Also, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886647/cant-install-via-pip-because-of-egg-info-error), but that's not the issue I am having.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27703117/1378264

(install flup6 instead flup because flup does not work with python3)

Answer (score 0):

## Use `flipflop` instead

```
pip3 install --upgrade flipflop
```

[`flipflop`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flipflop) is what did the trick for me.
`flup-py3` has an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/Pyha/flup-py3.3/issues/2) which has been standing open for a couple of years now.

Do not forget to [edit the import line](https://github.com/Kozea/flipflop) in your `.fcgi` script to reflect this change towards [using `flipflop`](https://github.com/Kozea/flipflop).